# Search code in the repositories whose name contains a keyword

Tags: github

In [github search](https://github.com/search), the following string allows me to search `JavaScript` code that contain `Acode` in all the repositories of the user `NameOfUser`:

```
user:NameOfUser language:JavaScript ACode
```

Now, I would like to **add another condition**: i am only interested in the code containing `ACode` in the repositories whose name **contains** `repokey`.

Does anyone know how to write the request?

Answer (score 0):

The search API already does this. You can just use the search that you've posted above to search for repositories containing the text you've specified.

For example...

> user:mrdoob language:JavaScript Three Extension

returns this...

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Amrdoob+language%3AJavaScript+Three+Extension&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure you understand my question... Taking your example, i would want to look for `keyword` in the code of the repositories whose name contains `Three`... So the question is how to add the constraint `keyword`...

Comment: Apologies. Slight misunderstanding. Amended my answer to cater for that scenario. You can add as many keywords to the search as you wish to match on for the repository name. If this isn't what you're looking for, then the question would appear to be unclear to me.

Comment: Errr... `user:mrdoob language:JavaScript Three Extension` does find the repositories whose name contains `Three` and `Extension` (ie, `mrdoob/THREE.InspectorExtension`), but it did not look for the `keyword` in the code of `mrdoob/THREE.InspectorExtension`. My requirement is to find the code in `user:mrdoob language:JavaScript Three Extension` that contains e.g., `WebGLBufferRenderer`.

Comment: You should probably update your question to reflect that requirement then. Your question states that you want repositories whose name includes keyword, not the code itself. And, TBH, I'm not sure you can even do that using GitHub's search mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

As above answer I also tried with type=Code and added a "WebGLBufferRenderer" keyword, See if it helps:

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Amrdoob+language%3AThree+Extension+WebGLBufferRenderer&type=Code&ref=searchresults